# Technical Specification Tools

Tags: planning, documentation

I am planning to write a technical specification document / functional specification for my personal project. Can anybody suggest any useful links / tools / templates that can help me?

I am mainly looking for tools (preferably freeware).

Comment: As @Mark said, there are plenty of templates available.  However, your mention of tools, and your combination of "technical specification document/functional spec" when those are two quite different things, makes me think you haven't quite nailed down what you're looking for -- templates, or automated tools that create docs out of data models, UX prototypes, etc.  Could you say more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

There are many free templates available, search on [technical specification template](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=technical+specification+template).

[docstoc has a technical specification template](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/17803814/Technical-Specification-Template) that looks clean and professional.

Unfortunately, I don't know of a tool that will do it automatically. When done right, doing it by hand, while cumbersome, can be really beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a great template](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1MU-fo5FlBbcz3R-Eg38lFtcAr5s_k2ynpd9ew0aButs/edit?usp=sharing)

[And a medium article based on the above template](https://goberoi.com/on-writing-product-specs-5ca697b992fd#.5stjy3h9j)

Comment: Link answers are discouraged (partly to avoid link rot, partly to avoid rickrolling).  Could you expand the summary of the links just a little bit more - enough to help someone decide whether clicking on the link is worth the risk of a rickroll, or if it is worth the effort to overcome potential linkrot?